# How to easily give if statement for checking one list contains some keyword

Tags: python-2.7

I want to check one list contains some keywords.

My writing is below:

```
if ('keyword1' or 'keyword2' or 'keyword3') in [list]:
```

above works, but seems not good writing.

Any other method to improve it?

Comment: That is not doing what you think it is doing.  Consider it this way: ``('keyword1' or 'keyword2' or 'keyword3')`` is a single expression, which necessarily evaluates to a single value (which happens to be ``'keyword1'`` in this case).  That one value is the only thing that ``in`` will be looking for within your list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python built-in `any` method, https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any

```
search_terms = ['a', 'keyword1']
list = ['blabla', 'keyword1', 'keyword4']
if any(word in list for word in search_terms):
 // TRUE
```